# How to exclude particular file name in a code in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on python project  encryption/decryption of a file
While encrypting the whole directory of file  including [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6TT.png) the main python code file also gets encrypted i.e `F_lock.py`

CODE:

```
def encrypt_all_files(self):
        dirs = self.getAllFiles()
        for file_name in dirs:
            self.encrypt_file(file_name)
```

So how it is possible to exclude this `F_lock.py file` not to be encrypted

Sorry I'm new to Python, I know this is probably basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code properly; use a code block (the `{}` icon) for code, for example.

Comment: An external image is very inconvenient. Either include the image in your question, but in this case, the image contributes little to nothing that you've already put in words. Just remove the image link.

Comment: `self.getAllFiles() ` is not a common method, hence we can't help you without seeing more code.

Comment: Why not, however, put an `if` statement in the for loop and check that `file_name` does not equal the file(s) you don't want to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much information is given about `self.getAllFiles()` and `self.encrypt_file(file_name)`. My answer is based on:

```
self.getAllFiles() # Return list of files with complete file address like C:\Folder\file.py
```

and

```
self.encrypt_file(file_name) # Take input file complete address
```

In such case, you have to find out file name from complete file address, which can be done by using `os` library like below:

```
def encrypt_all_files(self):
        dirs = self.getAllFiles()
        for file_name in dirs:
            if not os.path.basename(file_name) == 'F_lock.py':
                self.encrypt_file(file_name)
```

You have to decide on the basis of contents in `dirs`, if it is complete address then you can use mentioned approach. On a basic note, you can check `file_name` as easy as `string` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check the names of each file and make sure that the file which you are going to encrypt is not the F_lock.py file.

`if not file_name.startswith("F_lock.py"):
           # rest of the code`